# How to add the computer name in LogicalDisk Powershell WMI Query

Tags: powershell, wmi-query

In the query below, I'd like to add the $srv value under the ServerName for each row.

```
[string]$srv = 'someserver'
gwmi -query "select * from Win32_LogicalDisk 
where DriveType = 2 OR DriveType = 3" -computername $srv | select ServerName, Name, FreeSpace,Size | export-csv -path .\$srv\BOX_LogicalDisk.csv -noType
```

I have tried adding $srv to the Select statement but no go.

Output should be like so:

```
ServerName  Name    FreeSpace   Size
Someserver  C:      82652930048 21340921856
Someserver  D:      7727915008  21340921856
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a calculated property with [`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx):

```
|select @{Name='ServerName';Expression={$srv}},Name,FreeSpace,Size
```

Comment: Nice, I have also found this:  Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -computername $srv | Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 3 -or $_.DriveType -eq 2 } | Select-Object SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,FreeSpace,Size | Export-Csv .\$svr\BOX_LogicalDisk.csv -NoTypeInformation

Answer (score 0):

Your command is returning all the data you need. Pipe it to format-list to see all properties like so:

```
gwmi -query "select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType = 2 OR DriveType = 3" -computername $srv | Format-List *
```

You'll see a PSComputerName property. So, just select it:

```
gwmi -query "select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType = 2 OR DriveType = 3" -computername $srv | select PSComputerName,Name,FreeSpace,Size
```